# value from MySQL needs to be refreshed

Tags: php, sql, refresh, gauge

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>TEST</title>
<script src="gauge.min.js"></script>
</head>

<?php 
        //maak verbinding met MySQL server:
        $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","opc") 
        or die("Kan niet verbinden met de server " . mysqli_error($link));

        //Haal waarde uit de database:
        $query = "SELECT * FROM test" 
        or die("Er is een fout opgetreden" . mysqli_error($link));

        //Sla de waarde op.
        $result = $link->query($query);

        //toon informatie:

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
        {
            $waarde2 = $row["waarde2"];
        }
?>

<body>    
    <canvas id="gauge1" width="400" height="400"        
        data-type="canv-gauge"
        data-title="OPC TEST"
        data-min-value="0"
        data-max-value="100"
        data-major-ticks="0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100"
        data-minor-ticks="10"
        data-stroke-ticks="true"
        data-units="RPM"
        data-value-format="3.0"
        data-glow="true"
        data-animation-delay="500"
        data-animation-duration="200"
        data-animation-fn="linear"
        data-colors-needle="#f00 #00f"
        data-onready="setInterval( function() { Gauge.Collection.get('gauge1').setValue( <?= $waarde2 ?>);}, 1000);"
    ></canvas>    
</body>    
</html>
```

It works perfectly and shows a gauge with the value from the mysql database (which updates itself every second with another value). Unfortunately the gauge keeps displaying the same number. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: By reloading the page?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Prefect answer for the perfect name.

Comment: I did think about that. but it's kinda ugly when the page refreshes every second. and now it's a second, but later it will be in milliseconds. i'm building a SCADA application in HTML5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the gauge and data pull into a DIV using AJAX and then update AJAX every **ms or seconds or whatever you need. Then it will just happen at the frequency you determine.

This is  a quick and easy way to do it: [Div Update](http://matthewaprice.com/simple-jquery-ajax-auto-refreshing-div/)

Comment: I now have an empty div which indeed refreshes itself with the value of the database. Many thanks for that! but the div itself can't be placed in the setValue of the gauge. Do you have an solution for that? or did i do something wrong here.

Comment: @user2890367 Place the PHP and the <canvas>...</canvas> into the separate PHP file that ajax is calling, then it will all refresh in the div