# Blank HTML canvas with DIV-refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have 2 file, both php. File A contains:

```
<?php

// Datum aanmaken om bovenaan de pagina te zetten
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');
$vandaagtijd = date("d-m-Y, H:i");

include_once "/externalpw/mysql_pw.php";
$link = mysql_pconnect($MyHostname, $MyUsername, $MyPassword) or die("Error verbinden met DB: " . mysql_error());


//Eerst de elektra en het gas selecteren in die database en dan daarmee aan de gang
$db = mysql_select_db("elekgas", $link);
if (!$db) {
        mysql_close($link);
        die("Error selecteren DB: " . mysql_error());
}

// Actuele waaarden op van huidig verbruik en meterstanden
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT gebr_laag_tarief AS glt, gebr_hoog_tarief AS ght, leve_laag_tarief AS llt, leve_hoog_tarief AS lht, huidig_verbruik AS hv, huidig_levering AS hl, gas FROM meetwaarden ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
if (!$result1) {
        mysql_close($link);
        die("Error met query1: " . mysql_error());
}
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
        $glt = $row['glt'];
        $ght = $row['ght'];
        $llt = $row['llt'];
        $lht = $row['lht'];
        $hv  = $row['hv'];
        $hl  = $row['hl'];
        $gas = $row['gas'];
}

?>


<!-- Metertjes js toevoegen -->
<script src="gauge.min.js"></script>
  <canvas id="gauge1"
   width="200" height="200"
   data-type="canv-gauge"
   data-title="Vermogen"
   data-min-value="0"
   data-max-value="6000"
   data-major-ticks="0 1000 2000 3000 4000 5000 6000"
   data-minor-ticks="10"
   data-stroke-ticks="true"
   data-units="Watt"
   data-value-format="4.0"
   data-glow="true"
   data-animation-delay="10"
   data-animation-duration="200"
   data-animation-fn="bounce"
   data-colors-needle="#dd0000 #0000ff"
   data-highlights="0 2000 #bbffaa, 2000 4000 #ffffaa, 4000 6000  #ffaaaa"
   data-onready="setInterval( function() { Gauge.Collection.get('gauge1').setValue(<?= $hv; ?>);}, 1000);"
  ></canvas>
  </td>
  <td align="center">
  <canvas id="gauge2"
   width="200" height="200"
   data-type="canv-gauge"
   data-title="Vermogen"
   data-min-value="0"
   data-max-value="400"
   data-major-ticks="0 100 200 300 400"
   data-minor-ticks="5"
   data-stroke-ticks="true"
   data-units="kWh"
   data-value-format="3.2"
   data-glow="true"
   data-animation-delay="10"
   data-animation-duration="200"
   data-animation-fn="bounce"
   data-colors-needle="#dd0000 #0000ff"
   data-highlights="0 100 #a9feff, 100 300 #bbffaa, 300 400 #ffffaa"
   data-onready="setInterval( function() { Gauge.Collection.get('gauge2').setValue(<?= $hl; ?>);}, 1000);"
  </canvas>
```

File B contains:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<!-- Div refresh function -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
setInterval(function() {
$('#data').load('data.php');
}, 1000);
});
</script>

 <div id="data">Laden van gegevens... </div>
```

I have the correct head, body etc tags in file B so it makes a complete webpage. However, when I call file B in a browser, it doesn't paint the gauges. When I try to echo them, the correct values are displayed so they do come over from file A.

When I call file A directly, the gauges work just fine. Anybody any idea why it doesn't work? I followed the directions from this topic: [value from MySQL needs to be refreshed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449803/value-from-mysql-needs-to-be-refreshed). But no luck.

Comment: Hello fellow Dutchman! The code in your data.php (file A) is missing something (the `$result1` query is incomplete, it gets cut off at the end `huidig_verbruik AS hv, huidig_leveri$`). I'm assuming this should be continued as somthing like `huidig_levering AS hl` and so on...). Could you try and post the full code?

Comment: My bad, copied it from putty. When it is too long to display it cuts it off. Should have paid more attention :)
To make it complete, file A is also known as data.php and sits in the same folder as file B. The other values from the query in file A are also used in file B and they work just fine as well. It is just those HTML-canvas gauges that do not show :(

Comment: This is probably not your problem, but: 1. you include gauge.min.js again and again. 2. you're setting setInterval in data.php's output, and refreshing data.php in another setInterval. While it might work, I'm not sure this is the right thing to do

Comment: Point 1 I get, I shall move it to file B. Point 2 I don't get. I thought (and that might well be wrong) I wait until the document finishes loading and then I refresh it every X (milli)seconds. Please elaborate...

Comment: Moved the gauge.min.js to the <head> section of file B. As you pointed out, it was not the solution. I do get however, get the idea that it somehow doesn't include it if I refresh the gauges. Echo the values work just fine but the gauges don't show.
I wanted to comment in the topic I mentioned but I am to new to do so :(